# BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, xml, image

When I load the XML Tags inside the `ArrayList`

```
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static Context context;
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);

    //Hashmap für die XML-Tags
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> projectItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> taskItems = new ArrayList<>();

    // XML-Tags 
    static final String KEY_PROJECT = "_project"; //Projekt Eltern
    static final String KEY_UUID = "uuid";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_JOBTITLE = "jobtitle";
    static final String KEY_JOBINFO = "jobinfo";
    static final String KEY_PROJECTIMAGE = "image";
    static String projectImageString = "";

    // XML-Tags 
    static final String KEY_TASK = "task";
    static final String KEY_UUID_OBJ = "uuid_obj";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_INFO = "info";
    static final String KEY_OBJECT = "object";
    static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    static final String KEY_OBJECT_ID = "object_id";
    static final String KEY_OBJECT_SNR = "object_snr";
    static final String KEY_REGISTRATION_ID = "registration_id";
    static final String KEY_TASKIMAGE = "task_image";
    static final String KEY_TASK_HEADLINE = "task_headline";
    static final String KEY_TASK_SUBJECT = "task_subject";
    static final String KEY_TASK_ACTION = "task_action";
    static final String KEY_TASK_PRIORITY_COLOR = "task_priority_color";
    static final String KEY_TASK_STATUS = "task_status";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "example.xml");
        if (file.exists()) {

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(readFromFile("example.xml"));

            NodeList nodeListProject = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PROJECT);
            NodeList nodeListTasks = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TASK);

            //Schleife für Aufgaben
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListTasks.getLength(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                Element e = (Element) nodeListTasks.item(i);

                map.put(KEY_UUID_OBJ, parser.getValue(e, KEY_UUID_OBJ));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_INFO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_INFO));
                map.put(KEY_OBJECT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OBJECT));
                map.put(KEY_LOCATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOCATION));
                map.put(KEY_OBJECT_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OBJECT_ID));
                map.put(KEY_OBJECT_SNR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OBJECT_SNR));
                map.put(KEY_REGISTRATION_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_REGISTRATION_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TASKIMAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASKIMAGE));
                map.put(KEY_TASK_HEADLINE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_HEADLINE));
                map.put(KEY_TASK_SUBJECT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_SUBJECT));
                map.put(KEY_TASK_ACTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_ACTION));
                map.put(KEY_TASK_PRIORITY_COLOR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_PRIORITY_COLOR));
                map.put(KEY_TASK_STATUS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_STATUS));
                map.put(KEY_TASKIMAGE, parser.getValue(e,KEY_TASKIMAGE));

                taskItems.add(map);
            }

            // Schleife für Auftragsinfos
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeListProject.getLength(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                Element e = (Element) nodeListProject.item(i);

                map.put(KEY_UUID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_UUID));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                map.put(KEY_JOBTITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBTITLE));
                map.put(KEY_JOBINFO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JOBINFO));
                map.put(KEY_PROJECTIMAGE, parser.getValue(e,KEY_PROJECTIMAGE));



                projectItems.add(map);
            }

            try {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, projectItems,
                    R.layout.list_item_projects,
                    new String[]{KEY_JOBTITLE, KEY_JOBINFO},
                    new int[]{R.id.jobtitle, R.id.jobinfo});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //file.delete();

        } else {
            DownloadXMLFiles dlxmlf = new DownloadXMLFiles();
            dlxmlf.execute();
        }

        Log.v("onCreate: ", " MenuItems: " + projectItems);

        ListViewActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

XMLParser.java

```
public class XMLParser {
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(ListViewActivity.getAppContext());

public String getXMLFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        try {
            //defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return xml;
    //return xml
}

public Document getDomElement(String xml) {

    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));

        doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error Parser: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error SAX: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error IO: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return doc;
}

public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
    Node child;
    if (elem != null) {
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
                if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    return child.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

My decodeBase64 method:

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

I want to know how i can add the Image parsed from the XML to the SimpleAdapter correctly. 
Do i have to create my own Adapter?

### Error:

```
05-05 12:39:17.425  17335-17335/de.app E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 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
05-05 12:39:17.425  17335-17335/de.app I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 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
05-05 12:39:17.685  17335-17335/de.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 478K, 25% free 2992K/3952K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
05-05 12:39:17.705  17335-17335/de.app E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 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
05-05 12:39:17.705  17335-17335/app I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 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
```

Comment: please show Your decodeBase64() method..

Comment: Are you sure `projectImageString` is correct?

Comment: parser.getValue(e,Key_PROJECTIMAGE) just give the string from the XML

Comment: Post the entire stack trace in your question, and all the relevant code.

Comment: that´s not the complete stacktrace...

Comment: okay now i added the stacktrace

Comment: why did you posted the above two classes ? Error is with Bitmap and the code calling the bitmap is not there ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can trap the FileNotFoundException and get the entire stack trace.
Might provide better ideas...